# caffe: what does BACKEND and SCALE mean in data layer definition?

Tags: neural-network, protocol-buffers, deep-learning, caffe

I'm a fresh guy to caffe.
and was following [mnsit handwritten digits recognize example](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html).

when seeing

```
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "Data"
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "mnist_train_lmdb"
    backend: LMDB
    batch_size: 64
  }
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
}
```

I was confused by the parameters.
Could somebody explain what does the `backend` and `scale` parameter means?

and where can I find the definition of such params?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When facing confusing parameters in caffe's prototxt, you can always look at the [`$CAFFE_ROOT/src/caffe/caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto) file that defines the parameters. Most values have comments explaining them.

As for the parameters in your question,
Caffe supports two types of datasets for the `"Data"` layer: [lmdb](/questions/tagged/lmdb) and [leveldb](/questions/tagged/leveldb). The `backend` paramter allows you to specify what type is your input dataset `LEVELDB` or `LMDB`.

The `scale` parameter is part of the [`transform_param`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L407), the comment in `caffe.proto` reads:

> ```
> // For data pre-processing, we can do simple scaling and subtracting the
> // data mean, if provided. Note that the mean subtraction is always carried
> // out before scaling.
> ```

Comment: Thank You! Shai, This is what I was looking for!